# why navigation test failed in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am navigate from one page to another on button click using angular ?.I am able to navigate .But I am trying to test that scenario .I am getting a error .here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/fcBzwfM168iKFOC0hv2W?p=preview

**Testcase**

```
it('should go to state 2', function() {
            scope.moveToSecondPage();
            scope.$apply();

            console.log("---")
            console.log($state1)
            expect($state1.get('state2').views.testView.templateUrl).toBe(view2);
        })
```

**JSCode**

```
.controller('cntrl',function($scope,$state){

  $scope.moveToSecondPage=function(){
    //alert('--')
    $state.go('state2')
  }

})
```

Comment: Everyone thing works fine, no errors in your console. So I wouldn't worry about that error.

Comment: please check  Unexpected request: GET partials/state2.html
No more request expected

Comment: please check plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/fcBzwfM168iKFOC0hv2W?p=preview ..test is not working

Comment: I am curious as to why you specify a controller for state1, but not for state2

Comment: I don't need to do anything in controller 2 ..that why I didn't write it ..what is effect on testing ..I need to pass my test case